# Python - error when making a socket connection (server - target)

Tags: python, sockets, error-handling, serversocket

(Using Python 3) I am trying to connect server and client and symply send a message from one to another but I don't know why I get this strange error: **OSError: [WinError 10057]**. Does anyone know why it happened? I did a bit of reaserch but didn't find anything, I think I made an error when making global variables, or is it somenthing with message encoding and decoding?

**Here is my full error:**

File "server_side.py", line 34, in 
shell()

File "server_side.py", line 6, in shell
s.send(command.encode('utf-8'))

OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a
sendto call) no address was supplied

**Here is my server_side code:**

```
import socket

def shell():
    command = input('[+] Insert command: ')
    s.send(command.encode('utf-8')) 
    message = target.recv(1024)
    print(message.decode('utf-8'))

s = ''
target = ''  
ip = ''

def server():

    global s
    global target
    global ip    

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    s.bind(('192.168.1.109', 54321))#target ip, port more bit isti
    s.listen(5)

    print('[+] Listening for connections')
    target, ip = s.accept()
    print('[+] Connection established from: %s' %str(ip))

server()
shell()
```

**And this is my client_side code:**

```
import socket

def shell():
    command = sock.recv(1024)
    message = 'Hello there'
    sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('192.168.1.109', 54321)) #home ip

shell()

sock.close()
```

My command input on server_side example vould be the word : Hello, or somenthing like that.

Comment: Have you considered looking up Winsock error 10057?

Answer (score -1):

You have to put the `shell()` function in a infinite loop, and you have to run the server_side code and then the client_side code.

Here is a bit changed code:
Server side code:

```
import socket

def shell():
    command = input('[+] Insert command: ')
    s.send(command.encode('utf-8')) 
    message = target.recv(1024)
    print(message.decode('utf-8'))

s = ''
target = ''  
ip = ''

def server():

    global s
    global target
    global ip    

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    s.bind(('192.168.1.109', 54321))#target ip, port more bit isti
    s.listen(5)

    print('[+] Listening for connections')
    target, ip = s.accept()
    print('[+] Connection established from: %s' %str(ip))
while True:
   server()
   shell()
s.close()
```

Client side code:

```
import socket

def shell():
    command = sock.recv(1024)
    message = 'Hello there'
    sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('192.168.1.109', 54321)) #home ip

while True:
    shell()

sock.close()
```

Comment: He is calling `accept()`, and the client can connect even if he doesn't, up to a point, because of the TCP backlog.

Comment: @ user207421 Sorry missed it

Comment: I tested your code and it gives me the same error